# Can I use jsoup to counts javascript libraries used in web pages found on Google

Tags: javascript, java, jsoup

I am planning to analyse the top javascript libraries used in the web-pages found on Google search.

While doing the initial analysis, `jsoup` seems to be a good choice to connect to google and get the search results.

On top of this, I want to go to each and every search result URLs to get the javascript libraries used.

Does `jsoup` provides support this feature. Or for my use-case, any other libraries I can use on top `jsoup`.

**Note** : I am in analysis phase, yet to start the development?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Jsoup you have to make sure the page your're parsing is not dynamically modified by javascript. So there are two things to consider:

- Are all the links you want to parse in page source and are not added dynamically into DOM after the page is loaded? You can test it by disabling javascript in your browser and browsing page. Google works without javascript so that's not a problem.
- Are all the scripts in the page source and no scripts are added by javascript after the page is loaded?
  You can check it by analyzing raw page source visible in most browsers with using "View source" option and comparing your results with what you get by using firebug/inspector.

If you want to parse many pages the result may be missing dynamically loaded libraries. Jsoup will find:

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

but it will not be reliable to parse:

```
<script>
    new Element("script", {src: "jquery-3.3.1.min.js", type: "text/javascript"});
</script>
```

because this one would require executing javascript.